# How to create TypeScript defs for third-party lib function that returns module itself

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

Not sure if I worded the title correct. I'm creating a type declaration file for the NPM package *prompt*. The library itself is created like this:

```
var prompt = module.exports = Object.create(events.EventEmitter.prototype);
prompt.started = false;
/* ... */
prompt.start = function (options) {
    /* ... */
    prompt.memory = options.memory || 10;
    /* ... */
    prompt.started = true;
    return prompt;
}
/* ... */
```

I'm trying to figure out how to create the .d.ts file by following instructions inside DefinitelyTyped's autogenerated types/prompt/index.d.ts file.

Looks like I would put

```
export function start(options?: promptOptions): **????**
```

to define the `prompt.start` we see above. I've already got

```
export let started: boolean;

export interface promptOptions {
    memory?: number;
    allowEmpty?: boolean; // etc.
}
```

but I'm not sure what type the function should return. It appears to be returning a modified version of the module itself. How should I structure the .d.ts file? Thanks.

Comment: I'd bet that `memory` and` `started` keys already exist, but `start()` simply sets new values for them. Which means that `require('prompt')` and `prompt.start()` probably return the exact same type.

Comment: `memory` does not. `start()` creates it. In any case, your comment gets to the heart of what I don't understand: even if what you say were true, *what* to I define as the return type for `start()`? It seems to return the module's own export, so somehow I need to import my own index.d.ts into the same file  as something like PromptModule and then put `export function start(/*...*/): PromptModule;` ??? How is this accomplished from within a single index.d.ts file?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just create a type, and use it two places of your `.d.ts` file.

I'm new to typescript, but I think you want something like this:

```
// Set the type of the module.
export = Prompt

interface PromptOptions {
    memory?: number;
    allowEmpty?: boolean;
}

type Prompt = {
  memory?: number,
  started: boolean,

  // this type has a method that return itself.
  start(PromptOptions): Prompt
}
```